# Assistance writing to csv with python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the simple script below to strip down IPs. All items in the list print out just fine (z) - but when writing to the csv file, only the last entry is written instead of the all items as in z. Any help would be great, thanks!

```
import csv, sys

imported_csv = sys.argv[1]


def remove_commas():
    with open(imported_csv, 'r') as file:
        reader = csv.reader(file, delimiter=',')

        for i in reader:

            x = i[0]
            y = x.split(",")
            z = y[0]
            print(z)

            csv_file = open('sample2.csv', 'w+')
            csv_file.write(z)
            csv_file.write('\n')
            csv_file.close()

remove_commas()
```

Comment: The line `y = split(",")` does not do anything, since `csv.reader` already gives you the separated fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to open `sample2.csv` in `a` or `a+` mode.

- `a` is for *append*
- `w` is for *write*
- `+` is for *update mode (read and write)*

So...  you are over-writing your file each time. 
The below should solve your mentioned issue with only one line appearing.

```py
import csv, sys

imported_csv = sys.argv[1]


def remove_commas():
    with open(imported_csv, 'r') as file:
        reader = csv.reader(file, delimiter=',')

        for i in reader:

            x = i[0]
            y = x.split(",")
            z = y[0]
            print(z)

            csv_file = open('sample2.csv', 'a')
            csv_file.write(z)
            csv_file.write('\n')
            csv_file.close()

remove_commas()
```

Comment: Ahhh! Thank you!

Comment: The '+' is not needed; just `'a'` will do.

Comment: I understand that you didn't want to alter the original code too much, but opening and closing the file at each iteration looks a bit silly.

Comment: That is true, but this is not a code review. We want to answer his question. If he begins to experience speed issues, or has the desire to improve his program, the onus is on him to continue his research. But yes, it is very silly to repeatedly open and close the file. it would be much better to open both files in the original `with` statement.

Answer (score 0):

You need to open the file with `"a"` permission: `"w+"` is for writing *and* reading, but writing implies truncation when it's opened. `"a"` is for appending to a file (or creating when non-existent).

See the [Python documentation on open](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#open):

```
Character   Meaning
'r'     open for reading (default)
'w'     open for writing, truncating the file first
'x'     open for exclusive creation, failing if the file already exists
'a'     open for writing, appending to the end of the file if it exists
'b'     binary mode
't'     text mode (default)
'+'     open a disk file for updating (reading and writing)
```